# Generate .REG file from within VB6 app?

Tags: vb6, registry, export

Is it possible to export a branch of the registry and generate a `.REG` file from within a VB6 app?

Comment: You could write your own using API calls but natively VB6 doesn't have any more complex registry calls than GetSetting, SaveSetting, DeleteSetting and GetAllSettings (which limit you to a particular area of the registry for VB6 app settings). http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=563162 seems to be a good starting point for understanding registry access in VB6.

Comment: Also http://windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/windows/2004/06/15/VB_Registry_Keys.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pages Michael linked to in the comments are certainly useful and informative regarding general registry access techniques from VB 6, but they don't really answer your question.

What you want is the Win32 [`RegSaveKeyEx` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724919.aspx), which will save the information from the specified registry key out to a file. Presumably, this is the same function used by the Registry Editor utility to export the selected key to a `.reg` file.

To call this function from VB 6, all you need to do is add a declaration to your project:

```
Public Declare Function RegSaveKeyEx Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegSaveKeyExA" ( _
    ByVal hKey As Long, _
    ByVal lpFile As String, _
    ByRef lpSecurityAttributes As Any, _
    ByVal flags As Long) As Long
```